# Can I set conditional variables for an object with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set variables for the object based on what the if statement decides the variables should be.

```
                    const object = {
                                name: name,
                                subject: subject,
                                text: text,
                            };

                            if (1 >2){
                                var name = 'Lionel'
                                var subject = 'Hello';
                                var text = 'Is it me your looking for?';

                            }else{
                                var name = 'Queen'
                                var subject = 'Bicycle!!';
                                var text = 'I want to ride one!';                                   

                            }

                     console.log(object);
```

Current output:
{ name: undefined, subject: undefined, text: undefined }

Desired output:
{ name: Queen, subject: Bicycle!!, text: I want to ride one! }

Comment: You kind of need to assign the variables before you try using them in an object...

Comment: Do you want to just check that if-statement one time on creation of the object or do you consider to later change some values in the object and want the if-statement to be run each time again?

Comment: This feels like you simplified your question too much. What is your actual case?

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating the created object. Try this

```
let obj = {
  name: name,
  subject: subject,
  text: text,
};

if (1 > 2) {
  obj.name = 'Lionel'
  obj.subject = 'Hello';
  obj.text = 'Is it me your looking for?';
} else {
  obj.name = 'Queen'
  obj.subject = 'Bicycle!!';
  obj.text = 'I want to ride one!';
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: your code throws an error: ReferenceError: name is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the `undefined` result is that you are referencing the variables before their declaration.

You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (if there are only two options) like this:

```
const object = 1 > 2 ? 
   {
    name: "Lionel",
    subject: "Hello",
    text: "Is it me you'r looking for"
   } : 
  {
   name: "Queen",
   subject: "Bicycle!!",
   text: "I want to ride one!"
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it at object initialization using the ternary operator [condition ? exprT : exprF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```js
let condition = (1 > 2);

let obj = {
  name: condition ? 'Lionel' : 'Queen',
  subject: condition ? 'Hello' : 'Bicycle!!',
  text: condition ? 'Is it me your looking for?' : 'I want to ride one!'
};

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor function instead of randomly renaming variables arbitrarily.

As a side note **don't** use *var* to declare variables in code blocks. It makes a variable global and this will cause collision, especially with code at your level. Use *let* instead.

The beauty of the constructor( the function called *construct* ) is that it doesn't mutate the object already stored in the variable `object`, it creates a new one and replaces what's already in `object`. This also prevents collision and weird code side-effects. This is inline with the **Functional Programming Paradigm**.

```js
let construct = (name, subject, text) => ({
    name: name,
    subject: subject,
    text: text,
  }),
  object;


if (1 > 2) object = construct('Lionel', 'Hello', 'is it me your looking for?');

else object = construct('Queen', 'Bicycle!!', 'I want to ride one!');

console.log(object);
```